# Pad a string using random numbers to a fixed length using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to pad a string with random numbers to meet a certain length (i.e. 10 characters). For example:

HAM --> HAM3481259 or TURKEY --> TURKEY6324

I've tried some JavaScript functions but I either had too many or no numbers at all. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you having trouble with here?  What part of this are you stuck on?  What have you tried?  What do you mean by "tried some JavaScript functions"?

Comment: If you need to figure out how many characters you need to pad, you can do `10 - str.length` (or `10 - (str.length % 10)` after checking if `str.length % 10 > 0`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the length and add a random digit, if smaller than the wanted length.

```js
function padRandom(string, length) {
    while (string.length < length) {
        string += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    return string;
}

console.log(padRandom('HAM', 10));
console.log(padRandom('TURKEY', 10));
```

Comment: What if I wanted to throw in padding with white space to this function? I know it can be done but I am inexperienced with functions but am trying to learn based on examples!

Comment: then add the space instead of `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)`

Comment: how about making it leading so that all of the existing characters are to the right?

Comment: i suggest to ask a new question. does any of the here given answers answers your question? you could have here a look, too: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Slightly faster version of [Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43333250/227927):

```js
function padRandom(string, length) {
    random_number_length = length - string.length;

    if (random_number_length > 0) {
        string += randomFixedInteger(random_number_length);
    }

    return string
}

function randomFixedInteger(length) {
    return Math.floor(Math.pow(10, length-1) + Math.random() * (Math.pow(10, length) - Math.pow(10, length-1) - 1));
}

console.log(padRandom('HAM', 10));
console.log(padRandom('TURKEY', 10));
```